# Getting confused with pointers in C

Tags: c

I have written delete function in C, to delete whole linked list. Definition of function is

```
void delete(LIST **head)
{
  if(head)
    {
      delete(head->next);
      free(head);
      *head=NULL;
    }
}
```

while compiling I got error: request for member `next` in something not a structure or union.

 The structure is

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Comment: Removed [C++] tag. This cannot possibly be a C++ question. `delete` is a keyword in C++.

Comment: Be careful with recursion - a very long list could cause a stack overflow. I'd use a loop instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`head` is a pointer to a pointer to `LIST`.  You need to dereference it - `*head` - to get a `LIST*` to operate on

```
void delete(LIST **head)
{
    if(*head)
    {
        delete(&(*head)->next);
        free(*head);
        *head=NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I made changes in my program as per your suggestions and it works. But when I am trying to execute, it terminates with error Segmentation fault (core dumped). I am unable to figure out. Can you help me to figure it out.

Comment: The `delete` function is correct so the problem is likely in code you haven't posted.  Can you create a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates the crash and post it as part of a new question please?